# Laravel can't load css file

Tags: css, laravel

I can't load css file in my Laravel project.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">
```

/public/css/style.css does exist IDE confirms, and my target blade file extends the base file where css is loaded. But still changes in css won't take effect.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blade file where you are declaring the assets try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

You can know more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, why this unusual convention?

Comment: laravel has its own conventions, you can find out more at : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset

Comment: @Vojta, Because Laravel masks the /public route, you don't access files that way. That's why your home directory is "/" instead of "/public/index.php"